# Evaluate $\Im(\operatorname{Li}_3(2i) + \operatorname{Li}_3(\frac i2))$

Tags: complex-analysis, polylogarithm

Applying the trilogarithm identity
$$ \operatorname{Li}_{3}\left(z\right) - \operatorname{Li}_{3}\left(1 \over z\right) =
-{1 \over 6}\ln^{3}\left(-z\right) -
{\pi^{2} \over 6}\ln\left(-z\right)\tag{1}
$$
along with $\Im\operatorname{Li}_{3}\left(z\right) =-
\Im\operatorname{Li}_{3}\left(-z\right)$,
I am able to obtain
$$
\Im\operatorname{Li}_{3}\left(2{i}\right) +
\Im\operatorname{Li}_{3}\left({{i} \over 2}\right) =
{\pi^{3} \over 16} + {\pi \over 4}\ln^{2}2
$$
However, the identity (1) seems a blackbox to me, offering little intuition. I would like to see the expression evaluated independently, preferably, self-contained.

Comment: Can you use the definition $z=re^{i\theta},-z=re^{i(\theta+\pi)} to derive the expression using the series definition of Li?

Comment: **Read Lewin.**

Answer (score 1):

Special functions are always. They are for eternity. But to find a common definition mathematicians do very very hard. I would solve this with a formula collection for example Abramovitch, Stegun nowadays in the Springer Verlag available.

The first equation is following Wolfram Alpha, which is available online, a series expansion for the left-hand side difference. This is polylog with n=3 common name is trilog or trilogarithm. The pod from WolframAlpha is:

[image: trilog expansion]

This is slightly different to the given one. This is called the Puiseux series expansion. This can be found in the wikipedia.org. For Polylog [Polylogarithm in wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm)  there is the identity:

[image: Polylog identity]

This evaluates to

```
-(1/6) ln[-z] (π^2 + ln[-z]^2)
```

and there is Your result. The section is named relationships to other functions. Here to the Riemann zeta function. s==3 in this case. The evaluation can be done too with Wolfram Alpha. This is proven by [Jonquiere in 1889](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#CITEREFJonqui%C3%A8re1889) in research on the functional equation for the Hurwitz zeta function.

Using the first equation with the identity gives the left-hand side in general for the imaginary part. So the calculation has to be done on the right-hand side of equation `(1)` at `z==2i`.

```
-(1/6) ln[-z] (\[Pi]^2 + ln[-z]^2) /. z -> 2 I

-(1/6) (-((I )/2) + 
   ln[2]) (^2 + (-((I )/2) + ln[2])^2)
```

The imaginary part of this is:

```
 (^2/16 + /4 ln[2]^2
```

That is the confirmation that Your identity is correct. A simple verification as simplification and symbolic representation of the result.

The above difference is probably just formally.